# Paypal Express Checkout (SOAP) - Get transaction fee

Tags: php, soap, paypal

I'm using the [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) package on Laravel Framework on Wamp Server on Windows 8.1 and I was wondering if I can get paypal's fee. so I dumped the response of the execution and the `"transaction_fee" {..}` was empty although in their documentation it wasn't empty, and there's some errors inside the response.
The reason I see those errors and I don't receive the `transaction_fee` is because I created in sandbox?

Paypal Execution Response:

```
{
"id":"PAY-7HC461155B029844JKWKQICQ",
"create_time":"2015-07-02T09:27:38Z",
"update_time":"2015-07-02T09:27:58Z",
"state":"approved",
"intent":"sale",
"payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal",
    "payer_info":{
        "email":"XXX@XXX.com",
        "first_name":"XXX",
        "last_name":"XXX",
        "payer_id":"ZTRB28BXCJCTJ",
        "shipping_address":{
            "line1":"XXX",
            "city":"XXX",
            "state":"",
            "postal_code":"",
            "country_code":"XXX",
            "recipient_name":"XXX"
        }
    }
},
"transactions":[
    {
        "amount":{
            "total":"10.00",
            "currency":"EUR",
            "details":{
                "subtotal":"10.00"
            }
        },
        "description":"XXXXXX",
        "item_list":{
            "items":[
                {
                    "name":"XXX",
                    "price":"10.00",
                    "currency":"EUR",
                    "quantity":"1"
                }
            ],
            "shipping_address":{
                "recipient_name":"XXX",
                "line1":"XXX",
                "city":"XXX",
                "state":"",
                "postal_code":"",
                "country_code":"XXX"
            }
        },
        "related_resources":[
            {
                "sale":{
                    "id":"217224619C549403J",
                    "create_time":"2015-07-02T09:27:38Z",
                    "update_time":"2015-07-02T09:27:58Z",
                    "amount":{
                        "total":"10.00",
                        "currency":"EUR"
                    },
                    "payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER",
                    "state":"pending",
                    "reason_code":"RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION",
                    "protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE",
                    "protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
                    "parent_payment":"PAY-7HC461155B029844JKWKQICQ",
                    "transaction_fee":{

                    },
                    "links":[
                        {
                            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/217224619C549403J",
                            "rel":"self",
                            "method":"GET"
                        },
                        {
                            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/217224619C549403J/refund",
                            "rel":"refund",
                            "method":"POST"
                        },
                        {
                            "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7HC461155B029844JKWKQICQ",
                            "rel":"parent_payment",
                            "method":"GET"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"links":[
    {
        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7HC461155B029844JKWKQICQ",
        "rel":"self",
        "method":"GET"
    }
]
```

}

Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: I did some research and I found this comment "Intl: The payment is pending because you hold a non-U.S. account and do not have a withdrawal mechanism. You must manually accept or deny this payment from your Account Overview."

So, If I don't line in US, I can't use Express Checkout? what is going on?

Comment: After hours of testings, I finally fixed this problem (partly). I changed the currency from EUR to USD and it worked. but still, I need it to be EUR.